# html2canvas - render picture without displaying the page

Tags: php, api, html2canvas

I have php API with $_POST , where i am getting API key and QR code from the request.
Then my php server generates the html code with `<div>, <img> <html> <body>` etc.. it means full website - getting data from the mysql server and rendering to html page.
At the end of the php code i have javascript code like this:

```
?>
<script>


    window.scrollTo(0, 0);

html2canvas(document.getElementById("SelectorToPrint")).then(function (canvas) {
    var dd= canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg",1);

    $.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "https://myserver/API/sendimg.php",
  data: { 
      key: '<?php echo $key;?>',
      barkod: '<?php echo $qrcode;?>',
     img: dd
  }
}).done(function(o) {

});

});

</script>
```

When i am displaying the page, the picture is being saved (using html2canvas js) , everything is OK.

The problem is, when i am calling this API request from another php code, the page is not displaying, and for this reason the picture is not rendered.

Is there some way to render html page and save a picture without displaying the generated html code?

I changed the code for a while - to not have $_POST  , but $_GET and testing with this code:

```
<?php
    $key='my_api_key';
    $qrcode='my_code';

    $test = file_get_contents('https://myserver/API/apipage.php?key='.$key.'&qrcode='.$qrcode);
    //var_dump($test) ;
?>
```

when the var_dump is removed from the code, the page is not rendered and the picture is not saved. When i enable the var_dump (or simply print_r or echo )  the picture is generated correctly. The problem is, that i dont want to display the html code (i think it's normal when i am talking about API calls).

Thanks for any hint

Comment: You are using _client-side_ functionality here, so of course you will have to return something for the client to work with here. If you don’t want that - then you need to check if there is a way to create the image using any server-side techniques somehow. (Since you told us virtually nothing about what exactly you are doing, _what_ you are taking a snapshot of here, there is little more advice to give on that right now.)

Comment: @CBroe  - I am trying to generate something like "visit cards" by using API calls. I was googling last few days, but found no correct answer, how to render images server-side

Comment: Image creation/manipulation using PHP usually involves either the GDlib functions, or Imagick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK so my solution was the following:

installed xvfb on my linux server

installed ssh2 for php

installed CutyCapt on my linux server

instead of calling and rendering picture directly - i am calling with specially created user (with privileges only to do this job) the following script directly from php API

```
 "/usr/bin/xvfb-run --server-args='-screen 0, 1920x1080x24' /usr/bin/CutyCapt --url='{$url}' --zoom-factor=1.4 --out=/home/myuser/public_html/rendered_images/{$filename}.{$extension}"
```

so as i learnt, there is no easy way to do it, but it's doable

hope it helps for someone